# Apache Vhosts behind Proxmox using default vhost webroot

Tags: apache, web-hosting

I am currently running a test system that will be hosting a variety of resource for my work place. On this test system I am running proxmox with 1 public IP address. I am using IP masquerading to allow my guest running apache to display webpages (ideally) on port 8008. 
At this time I can get a web page to be produced, but it doesn't follow my vhosts settings. 
This is a Ubuntu 17.04 installation using apache 2.4.25. 
Currently I am trying to host a subdomain called books..com on a non standard port, at this time, 8008. 
My vhost is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *                                                                                                                                                                                   
Listen 8008                                                                                                                                                                                          
<VirtualHost *>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ServerName books.<domain>.net                                                                                                                                                                       
ServerAlias books.<domain>.net books.<domain>.net:8008  www.books.
<domain>domain.net                                                                                                                   
(Defualt Vhost Comment about Server names)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                                                                                     
DocumentRoot /sites/books.<domain>.net/html                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
(Some Default Apache Vhost Comments)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ErrorLog /sites/books.<domain>.net/logs/error.log                                                                                                                                                   
CustomLog /sites/books.<domain>.net/transfer.log combined                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 (Some Default Apache Vhost Comments)                                                                                                                                             
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have my site data in the specified directory in the vhost, I have the site enabled, I have even tried specifying the port in the vhost. All this and when I visit the site, it still tries to load information from the default vhost's Doc root on /var/www/html. I have reloaded apache god knows how many times and restarted the entire guest system. 
And unfortunately every time you look up docroot issues with Vhosts, all the answers are due to "you copied a default Vhost and didn't change the docroot" or the site wasn't enabled. 
Any and all help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue. It's not just a matter of activating your site or changing the docroots (if you copy the default Vhost).

You must disable 000-default by running a2dissite 000-default.conf then reloading apache (systemctl reload apache2.service).

Thanks for anyone who gave this a shot.